# How to load dataset in Unity fom Vuforia dynamically?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I'm building an augmented reality app, so far, for each new marker I had to add to my Vuforia dataset, download it, put it in Unity, create the imagetarget and build the app again. This is very labor intensive, and delay the addition of new markers, because the time between I update it at PlayStore/App Store can take several days.

What I'm trying to do is a way that I can either load all my markers from the cloud (Tried that, with 2 markers some weird bug started happening) or when I open the app, it'll download the dataset with all the markers, create each image so that no matter how many markers I add or remove, all of them will be there at anytime the app is opened.

Answer (score 1):

Use Cloud Recognition Service From Vuforia: 
https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Training/Cloud-Recognition-Guide 
and here is a tutoria how to use it :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ILVpISTEcx4